# Html and Css Text Box Mixing with navigation menu

Tags: html, css

I Created this page with the help of some tutorial and I edited the code to attach a text box in the center of the page but the text box is mixing with the navigation menu. Some Help Would be appreciated. I have very less knowledge of html and css so please guide me in a simple way. I searched on the google and also got a w3 article but that did not help as I have used it in the css as yu can can see I have used margin-top , bottom , left and right to solve problem but instead it is mixing or overlapping it self with the navigation menu.

```css
body {
  background: url('nature.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

div.transbox {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  /* For IE8 and earlier */
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

div.transbox p {
  margin: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="About.html">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a>Camp Sites</a></li>
      <li><a>Mission</a></li>
      <li><a>Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Todo.html">Things to do</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Activities</a></li>
      <li><a>Parks</a></li>
      <li><a>Shops</a></li>
      <li><a>Events</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Map</a></li>
      <li><a>Directions</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="News.html">News</a></li>

</ul>

<div class="background">
  <div class="transbox">
    <p>This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.</p>
  </div>
</div>



</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what the intended output should be here. You might try playing around with [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) and [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Comment: That's true you should read more about CSS position property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
.background {
  clear: both;
}
```

This is to clear the float: left that was applied before.

[Read more on float](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/)